# Convert string timer to integer seconds

Tags: string, integer, greasemonkey

i'm trying to convert an string  like "0:13:30", which consist of h:mm:ss, to an integer which will be an answer of (m*60)+(s), working only with the minutes and seconds in greasemonkey or jscript.
What i curently have is:

```
var t_str = ''; var t_int =0;
var str1='';var str2='';var t_int1=0;var t_int2=0;

t_str="0:13:30";
alert(t_str);
str1=t_str[4]+t_str[5];
str2=t_str[2]+t_str[3];
t_int1=parseInt (str1);
t_int2=parseInt (str2);
t_int2=t_int2 * 60;
t_int=t_int1+t_int2;
alert(t_int);
```

I get up to the first alert. how do i get it to assign the values "13"  and "30" to str2 and str1? Sorry for a basic question, but im not used to this language :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var time = t_str.split(":"),
h = 3600 * parseInt(time[0], 10),
m = 60 * parseInt(time[1], 10),
s = parseInt(time[2], 10);
alert(h+m+s);
```

Comment: thanks. i changed it to : var time = t_str.split(":") ;
h = 3600 * parseInt(time[0], 10) ;
m = 60 * parseInt(time[1], 10) ;
s = parseInt(time[2], 10);
alert(h+m+s);   
  wasnt sure if it will work eith ','

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using javascript. If yes, then you can use split() method to split the t_str first and then carry on with your parsing of integers.

```
`str = t_str.split(":");` //- array of {0,13,30}
```

and then use this array to access your numbers.

Comment: Thanks, i see what u r trying to do in principle, but i'm not completely with u. i will use this and dig around a bit.